# How create a button click on intut

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two different forms. Each of them has its own submit button

```
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Submit" class="form-submit ajax-processed">
```

and

```
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit--2" name="op" value="Submit" class="form-submit ajax-processed">
```

I need to make a separate button that would click on these two input. How can I do this?

Comment: You need what now? A button that submit both forms?

Comment: Create a one button, which submit two forms.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403160/submit-two-forms-in-1-button

Comment: I try so:
`<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms()" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    submitForms = function(){
        document.getElementById("#edit-submit").submit();
        document.getElementById("#edit-submit--2").submit();
    }
</script>`
But it does not work.

Comment: It only submit the first one ? Sounds pretty normal to me

Comment: @Pearson you have to submit one of them using Ajax.

Comment: You are goign to have to make some kind of ajax solution , or how about ... combinning these 2 forms into one, since it seems that would work better anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 2 forms and only want 2 of them to be submited, they must have a common part, like a css class (no styling here, only a selector).

HTML part :

```
<form id="form1" class="myForm ..."/>
<form id="form2" class="myForm ..."/>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit both forms"/>
```

js :

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $(".myForm").submit();
});
```

You can add as many form as you want, if they have the class `myForm`, they will be submited too. No need to change your js code...

Comment: Forms have different ID
`<form action="/second_vote" method="post" id="advpoll-form-122" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Answer (score 0):

> Just provides the ids to your form.for example:

```
<form id="form1" class="myForm ..."/>
<form id="form2" class="myForm ..."/>

<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms()" />

<script>
   submitForms = function(){
     document.getElementById("form1").submit();
     document.getElementById("form2").submit();
   }
</script>
```